# How can I add only the first elements of an array in python?

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, addition

If I have an array, for example: a = np.array([[1,2], [2,5], [4,8]]), where the first digit represents the x value and the second one represents the y value, how can I add all of the first digits (x values) and all of the second digits (y values).
The output should look something like this:
7, 15
Thanks!

Comment: what did you try?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use numpy sum() for row axis (axis = 0). This sum the values in the same location of each row, or other way to say, it sums the values in the same column.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1,2], [2,5], [4,8]])
print(np.sum(a,axis=0))
```

Answer (score 3):

```
x, y = a[:,0].sum(), a[:,1].sum()
```

Answer (score 3):

Use numpy built-ins

```
np.sum(a,axis=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = np.array([[1,2], [2,5], [4,8]])
x = 0
y = 0
for element in a:
    x += element[0]
    y += element[1]
print("x: " + str(x))
print("y: " + str(y))
```

Output:

```
>> x: 7
>> y: 15
```

Access each element of the array and then for each element take first element as `x` and second as `y`

Comment: That's a very expensive way to use an ndarray. Numpy optimizes operations. Here you have to convert a numpy `int64` to a python `int` and do a python level function call and sum for each element. With the builtin .sum, none of this conversion is necessary.